# What is a word that describes "acceptance" and "understanding?"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I'm looking for a better word for "actions" in the following sentences.

> Foreign language classes help increase *acceptance* and *understanding* of other cultures. These **actions** are important, because ...

I need a word that describes the two words "acceptance" and "understanding." Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Probably [*tolerance*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage) would work for you [TFD]

> **tolerance** *n*
>   1. The capacity for or the practice of recognizing and respecting the beliefs or practices of others.

This is probably more skewed toward acceptance than understanding, but it does imply a certain level of understanding.

Comment: How could this word possibly be used to replace 'actions' in the OP's sentence?

Comment: Surely the primary sense of *tolerance* is much the same as *acceptance?* You can accept or tolerate something because you have no choice, for example - whether you *understand* it or not (whatever that's supposed to mean here! :)

Answer (score 1):

> *word that describes the two words "acceptance" and "understanding."*

A rather general, but frequently used term would be, "*appreciation*."

**Foreign language classes help increase the appreciation of other cultures**

> [**appreciation**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=appreciation+definition&gws_rd=ssl) *noun*: **1**. the recognition and enjoyment of the good qualities of someone or something. "I smiled in *appreciation*"; synonyms: valuing, treasuring, admiration, respect, regard, esteem, high opinion; see Google
>
> [**appreciation**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/appreciation) *noun*
>   1. Recognition of the quality, value, significance, or magnitude of people and things. 2. A judgment or opinion, especially a favorable one. see The Free Dictionary

Comment: Appreciation is a good answer. +1. FYI, using indentation to quote something actually creates (both visually, and semantically from an HTML perspective) a "preformatted code block", not a block quote. The problem with that is that as the browser understands the contents to be *preformatted*, and code, it will refuse to line-wrap it (as for code, that could change or interfere with its proper interpretation). This creates (awful) horizontal scroll bars. At a higher level, there's no need to quote he original question in your answer. It's understood that you're answering the question.

Comment: I know that feeling! Please do not feel as if I was criticizing you or your post: I was not (I upvoted it). I am trying to get in front of the recent trend here where answerers quote the question, which I find redundant, but you're not an offender; mostly it's new/one-off users I'm worried about. My concern with your post was only that we not set precedent with such an answer from a reputable user.  In re: Markdown, you have your priorities straight for sure. The general rule of thumb is: on EL&U, you'll almost never need preformatted (i.e. indented) blocks.

Answer (score 0):

**"assimilation"** comes to mind.

**"Foreign language classes help increase assimilation of other cultures"**

> - assimilation - (noun) The process whereby a minority group gradually adopts the customs and attitudes of the prevailing culture. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/assimilation)
> - assimilate - (verb)  to adopt the ways of another culture, to fully become part of a different society, country, etc. [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assimilate)

e.g. "They found it hard to assimilate to American society."

Answer (score 0):

Both acceptance and understanding include:

> *A series of actions or steps taken in order to achieve a particular end*

which is an ODO definition of a [process](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/process) and I think this fits your sentence well:

- Foreign language classes help increase acceptance and understanding of other cultures. These **processes** are important, because...

---

Or, if it doesn't strictly have to be one word:

aspects/forms of (cultural) [competence](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/competence#competence__4)

The term [cultural competence](https://books.google.rs/books?id=PaO3jsaGkeYC&pg=PA346&dq=cultural+competence+definition&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dAJQVc-nKIHbU9GQgKAO&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=cultural%20competence%20definition&f=false) is relatively new but one of its definitions (this seems to be susceptible to debate) is:

> *... the ability of individuals to accept, understand and relate effectively to culturally diverse groups of people.*

from: Encyclopedia of Cross-Cultural School Psychology edited by Caroline S. Clauss-Ehlers.

The frequency of usage of the terms "aspects" and "forms" also varies, as shown in this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aspects+of+cultural+competence%2C+forms+of+cultural+competence&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caspects%20of%20cultural%20competence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cforms%20of%20cultural%20competence%3B%2Cc0).

The whole sentence might read:

- Foreign language classes help increase acceptance and understanding of other cultures. These **forms of cultural competence** are important, because...

or

- Foreign language classes help increase acceptance and understanding of other cultures. These **aspects of cultural competence** are important, because...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am answering your original question. However, in place of  **actions** to describe both *acceptance* and *understanding* use

**skills**

**faculty,**  faculties (Shorter Oxford)

> An ability or aptitude, whether natural or acquired, for any special
>   kind of action.